# Java NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, парсер, jsoup, библиотеки

Есть класс который парсит сайт с помощью JSOUP, всё работает.
Но если вызываю этот класс не из IDE а через TomCat вылетает `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup`.

В Maven есть зависимость

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.2</version>
</dependency>
```

добавлял в проект напрямую, результат всё тот же.
В tomcat класс вызывается когда приходит "POST"

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if (req.getParameter("currency") != null) {
        new WebParser().parsePage();
    }
}
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(req,resp);
}
```

Но я не думаю что это как-то влияет...
(Я думаю что нужно явно тыкнуть в лицо библиотекой, только вот не знаю как)

Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: как вы через tomcat вызываете? напишите поподробнее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зависимость jsoup не доступна во время исполнения вашего кода в Tomcat. Скорее всего, вы не задеплоили соответствующий jar файл на tomcat.

Comment: Помогло добавление jar файла в /opt/tomcat/lib Всем спасибо !